# Java reactive programming. Thread management fundamentals

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive

I am learning Java RX Reactive programming. I am dwindled with a very basic question on the Asynch call that Java Reactive calls. So here is a scenario:
It is as follows:

```
input(a,b,c)
#1CPU op on a b c
#2Do some more CPU bound op
#3IO bound op ( calling DB to get 30 rows)
#4Business Logic
```

Now what I understand in normal non reactive programming, a worker thread would have been assigned to handle the request for input(a,b,c) and since #3 is a time-consuming op. this current thread might go to waiting state. Here comes the reactive framework and the current thread will be assigned to serve another input request instead of waiting to get all the records from DB and once we have all the records any available thread will cater execution #4 onwards. So my question is since the current thread left from #3 how will the next available thread will know from where to start execution? (i.e.#4) where and how JVM is storing the data and all executed information and varibables up until line #2? I belive simple call stack will not work here as there are multiple threads are running simultaneously. Please help me out.

Comment: `how will the next available thread will know from where to start execution?` what do you mean by "from where"? All it is just events, any thread schedules an event on the event loop. The event loop processes the event. When the result comes back from the database, it signals that there is job to be done, a thread schedules that there is a response to take care of of so an event is scheduled on the event loop and the event loop processes that event.

Comment: You have to put the state from the steps 1 to 3 into the consumer of the event for the #3 result by yourself. This is no longer "one method", but two loosely coupled steps.